# View PrintDocument on screen in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, preview

I create a custom PrintDocument class for printing. I handle the PrintPage event and use the Graphics object to output content to the document.

How can I in my WPF application show a "preview" of this document on screen? Is it possible?

I've tried to bind the PrintDocument to a DocumentViewer, but do not get any output. There is no visual PrintPreview component in WPF?

Comment: PrintDocument == GDI+ == WinForms. Not WPF friendly, maybe you can use the WinFormsHost control.

Comment: Maybe if I can work with a similar Graphics object and create an image of this to present with a FlowDocument?

Comment: A FlowDocument would be it's own preview, yes. A FixedDocument would work too.

Comment: Ok, i'll see if I can find a way to draw something here.